# Apache server-relative redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, httpd

Is it possible to implement a server-relative redirect using existing Apache features?

**[mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)** does have a [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) command, but that one always generates an absolute redirect even if configured like

```
Redirect /asdf /qwer
```

Also tried using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /asdf(.*) /qwer$1 [R,L]
```

The end result of either of these settings is the same:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://my-host.blah.blah:20085/qwer
```

But what I really need is:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: /qwer
```

--- EDIT ---

Yes, I know this is against RFC spec. But all modern browsers support a relative redirect, and I really need it for a temporary fix.

Answer (score 4):

That is the way Redirect works; from the manual:

> The new URL should be an absolute URL beginning with a scheme and
>   hostname, but a URL-path beginning with a slash may also be used, in
>   which case the scheme and hostname of the current server will be
>   added.

From [**RFC 2616, section 14.30**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30):

The field value consists of a *single* **absolute** URI.

Comment: It may be an incorrect redirect, but all modern browsers support it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: I never said it was incorrect, and his question was whether **apache** supports it. In short, no :)

Comment: His question was, importantly, _not_ `whether apache supports it`, but `[whether] it is possible…using existing Apache features`—[which it is](https://serverfault.com/a/840454/175102). I think this is not only a non-answer, but incorrect.